# Rspec undefined method 'matches?' error

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I tried to create a simple test suite in Rspec.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"

describe "User" do
  before (:all) do
    @ch = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  end
  it should "navigate to open2test" do
    @ch.get"http://www.open2test.org/"
  end
  it should "enter user name and email" do
    @ch.find_element(:id, "name").send_keys "jack"
    @ch.find_element(:id, "emailID").send_keys "jack@gmail.com"
  end
end
```

While executing `rspec file_name.rb`, I get:

```
"rspec/expectations/handler.rb:50:in `block in handle_matcher': undefined method `matches?' for "navigate to open2test":String (NoMethodError)"
```

Kindly update what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling both `it` and `should` methods.

```
it should "navigate to open2test" do
```

You should call only `it` here as you are using RSpec

```
it "should navigate to open2test" do
  # assert something
end
```

**Note** that shoulda has the below syntax with `Test::Unit`

```
should "do something" do
  # assert something
end
```

Comment: Works like charm :) thnx for the help